# Ionic 4: Toastcontroller css

Tags: ionic4

I have trouble finding the correct css code for changing the looks of a toast in Ionic 4.

In Ionic 3 you could use padding in css to change the look of a toast.
--min-height changes the height but it also places the message text to the top of the toast which I don't want.

I have this in my global.scss:

```
ion-toast.toast-mess {
text-align: center;
color: var(--ion-color-light);
font-size: 30px;
--border-radius: 30px;
padding: 50px;}
```

In the above code, padding is not taken into account, all other parameters work fine.

The default .toast-message says padding is available because it contains some default values.
How can I use padding again in custom css code, or something similar ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
--padding-end
--padding-start
--padding-top
--padding-bottom
```

Comment: and with --inner-padding-end: 50px  for example ?

Comment: No succes. I think the only way is overriding the default ".toast-message{ padding: 14px 16px }" should work, but I can't figure out how this one can be accessed in Ionic 4.

Comment: you can try to set no style encapsulation.                                                            import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core' and then add encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in your @Component.

Comment: I would also like to change the `max-width` of the toast content, because the `close` button gets pushed off the screen, but with Ionic, things are not as plain and simple as one would think